# Integrity constraint violation Doctrine 2 and Symfony

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm having some sort of textbuilder where you can add blocks to build up your text. The building blocks are defined in the database and when you add 1 to your text, it gets saved in the session (how you build them up).

But now when I try to persist the session to the database I get an:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'text' for key 'UNIQ_AA5F49C77153098'
```

He wants to add the existing definition of the building block, but it is already defined. The session itself is serialized.

So the steps that I'm doing to save is:

1) deserialize (
I also tried to merge it, but that didn't work either.)

2) persist to database => error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of persisting the unserialized object directly, do that: 
- unserialize the object
- fetch the object from database
- update the retrieved object with the value of the unserialized one
- persist the retrieved object

Does it work ?

Comment: I already tried that. I still got the same error. I also tried to get the buildingblock (the part that already exists in the database) and merge that so it hangs back in the system. But that doesn't work either.

Comment: it's really weird because it shouldn't fail on updating the entity. Could you edit your post with some code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're using the wrong association type for your model. I don't remember clearly but Doctrine adds a unicity constraints to unidirectional many to many or one to one associations.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with FOSUserBundle: I am not sure how to override the mapping configuration of an extended entity (in my case the field email_canonical, which was not used, but two empty fields also triggered the integrity violation).

I ended up with manually deleting the constraint in the database (and with app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql only updating the changes with the SQL command - except the UNIQUE Constraint)

As pointed out by futurecat: do you need your "text" field to be unique?

Comment: Well I fixed it by checking all the code and rewriting a stuff. The trick that futurecat explained did it.